# Should we do a bulk insertion operation in mongodb ?? will this block other Read / Write Operations?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb for our Application .

We have a very high usage of mongodb usage , you will know seeing this mongostat output

```
insert/s query/s update/s delete/s getmore/s command/s flushes/s mapped  vsize    res faults/s locked % idx miss %    q t|r|w  conn       time
       0       4        1        0         0         3         1  10396  11347    591        0      0.1          0      0|0|0    70   10:57:28
       0      65       31        0         0        35         0  10396  11347    591        1      3.7          0      0|0|0    70   10:57:29
       0      76       37        0         0        41         0  10396  11347    591        0      3.5          0      0|0|0    70   10:57:30
       0      85       42        0         0        44         0  10396  11347    591        1      4.7          0      0|0|0    70   10:57:33
       0      52       25        0         0        29         0  10396  11347    591        0      2.9          0      0|0|0    70   10:57:34
       0      26       11        0         0        15         0  10396  11347    591        0      1.1          0      0|0|0    70   10:57:36
       0      83       41        0         0        43         0  10396  11347    591        1      4.6          0      0|0|0    69   10:57:37
```

Regarding my query ,

As per our Application whenver a user logins into the Application , i need to store whatever the symbols the  user holds .
(A user might contain symbols within a  range from 20 to 100 )

**What is the best way to achieve the above insertion operation**

```
1. Perform a insert operation for each symbol individually 

Or 

2. Insert all the symbols at once this way 



public void insert(ArrayList<QuoteReportBean> quotelist) {
            DBObject[] totalrecords = new BasicDBObject[quotelist.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < quotelist.size(); i++) {
                QuoteReportBean reportbean = quotelist.get(i);
                BasicDBObject dbrecord = new BasicDBObject();
                dbrecord.append("cust", reportbean.getCustomerId());
                dbrecord.append("symbol", reportbean.getUniqueSymbol());
                dbrecord.append("access_time", reportbean.getDate());
                totalrecords[i] = dbrecord;
            }
         WriteResult result = coll.insert(totalrecords,WriteConcern.NORMAL);
         logger.info("quotelist" + result.toString());
    }
```

My concern is that as i  set the profiling level to 50

```
 db.setProfilingLevel(1,50)
```

and the insertion query with the second approach has been recorded in the system.profile collection

**Could you please tell me if the insert operation might lock other read / write operations ??**

Comment: Just answering you last line query: Every write operation in mongodb will block other read/write operation. This is because of single write lock per database. But write operations are very quick, so you will get good throughput. However reads can be parallel.

Comment: Missed the first question: batch insert in mongodb is very fast, but it does not report error back for all the failed writes. Only the last failed write is reported.

Comment: Did you read the locking FAQ for MongoDB? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending multiple objects to the database in an array is significantly faster than doing a separate insert for each object. It can be up to an order of magnitude faster, depending on the array size and the size of the objects.

The reason you might see your second statement (the batched/array insert) logged as a "slow query" is because it takes longer than a single insert, but it will definitely be faster than all the single inserts together.

Finally, your `mongostat` output does not look particularly dramatic.  MongoDB can easily do a few thousand operations per second (depending on the operation of course), so you're not anywhere close to hitting a limit, at least according to that screenshot.

Comment: You are right that making 10 sequential writes to the db is going to be slower than one batch write of 10.  However, you could also spin up 10 threads and make 10 parallel writes to the db.  Would this be faster than the bulk API?  I'm not sure.  I'd like to think that the batch operation could take a single write lock and somehow parallelize the writing on the DB side, but does it?

Comment: @skelly Bulk Insert saves significant resources by reducing RTTS. 10 threads would still take 10 RTTS instead of one RTT through bulk insert.